# Amplify PubSub not sending/receiving - no errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-iot

I have been struggling with this implementation and figured I'd ask for some community perspective at this point.

I've implemented PubSub with a Lambda successfully and when tested in the cloud I am seeing messages in the IoT test environment. I believe, therefore, that my endpoint is functional.

When trying to implement the Amplify service via the docs (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/pubsub/getting-started/q/platform/js/) I have been running into all sorts of issues. Worked through the "socket:undefined" issue by reinstalling lock file and node-modules. Now am not getting any errors but it simply is not connecting.

My code is below. Currently when I try to publish I'm getting a response of []. If I try to specify the provider I get this error - "Error: Could not find provider named AWSIoTProvider".

Note: I have been following various SOs - this one most recently:
[Amplify PubSub javascript subscribe and publish using cognito authorization: how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61637813/amplify-pubsub-javascript-subscribe-and-publish-using-cognito-authorization-how#)

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import { AWSIoTProvider } from '@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib/Providers';
import PubSub from '@aws-amplify/pubsub';

Amplify.addPluggable(new AWSIoTProvider({
  aws_pubsub_region: 'as-southeast-2',
  aws_pubsub_endpoint: 'wss://{MY_IOT_ID}-ats.iot.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/mqtt',
}));
Amplify.configure(config);

PubSub.configure();

PubSub.subscribe('myTopic1').subscribe({
  next: data => console.log('Message received', data),
  error: error => console.error(error),
  complete: () => console.log('Done'),
});
```

Then I have a function that I'm calling for publish that returns the [] if I don't specify the provider and the error above if I specify it (shown below)

Unspecified:

```
  await PubSub.publish('1234-abcd-9876/workitem', { msg: 'Hello to all subscribers!' })
              .then(response => console.log('Publish response:', response))
              .catch(err => console.log('Publish Pub Err:', err));
```

Specified:

```
  await PubSub.publish('1234-abcd-9876/workitem', { msg: 'Hello to all subscribers!' }, { provider: 'AWSIoTProvider' })
              .then(response => console.log('Publish response:', response))
              .catch(err => console.log('Publish Pub Err:', err));
```

Does anyone have any thoughts as to what I might be doing wrong here or might try next?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to only use Amplify or can you use the AWS SNS service and the AWS SDK?

Comment: @smac2020 I am open to using SNS and SDK - no problems with that really. Is there a decent whitepaper somewhere that outlines proper use clearly? Just was going w/ Amplify as the repo uses it and it seemed simple enough but we've already built a CloudWatch logger using the SDK so it's not a stretch to pivot in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying the specific error you got is  - `"Error: Could not find provider named AWSIoTProvider".`

so, change the import path for `AWSIoTProvider` to `@aws-amplify/pubsub` instead of using `@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib/Providers`.

```js
import { AWSIoTProvider } from '@aws-amplify/pubsub;
```